# Cut and join images in imagemagick on Ubuntu

Tags: imagemagick

I am a programmer with minimal understanding of `imagemagick`. I have a large set of `PNG` images from which I need to extract text through `Google Vision API`. Since this API is quite expensive I want to minimize the number of requests I make, so I want to join many images into single image which does not exceed 4MB size.

I have attached a sample image. [image]

1. This image has 30 blocks of user data. Each block has a blank photograph section. I want to delete this blank part (entire section after text to vertical line).
2. Join resultants images from 30 such images. I want to join all user data images from 30-40 images into single image. So its going to be like 900 user data blocks in one image.

I request some `imagemagick` experts to help me out.

Comment: What have you tried? You are supposed to put at least some effort in before asking a question. All the data blocks look the same so removing the photograph section is quite simple. As is making them into a large image - there are posts about doing that on this forum if you search.

Comment: Encoding flat black areas does not take much space, so removing them is unlikely to save you much.

Comment: @MarkSetchell But it will help me reduce width and height of the resultant image. Is not it?

Comment: Yes, but your question leads me to believe the Google Vision API is limited to 4MB not any height or width in pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can crop out columns 1, 2 and 3 like this:

```
convert sheet.png +repage -crop 240x+0+0 c1.png
convert sheet.png +repage -crop 240x+376+0 c2.png
convert sheet.png +repage -crop 240x+750+0 c3.png
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

And join back together as many as you like to get to 4MB, like this:

```
convert c1.png  c2.png c3.png +append result.png
```

[image]

I note the original is 22kB and the reduced one is 17kB.

---

Note that if you like this approach, you can do it all in one line as follows. I have not added the appending together part because that will be variable depending on the sizes:

```
convert sheet.png +repage \
   \( +clone -crop 240x+0+0   -write c1.png +delete \) \
   \( +clone -crop 240x+376+0 -write c2.png +delete \) \
   -crop 240x+750+0 c3.png
```

Comment: About a 20% saving on 30 images then @Mark Setchell The OP said he had 900 so should be within their 4MB limit. I wonder how well the OCR will work on that quality of image.

Comment: @Mark Setchell Thanks a lot, I will build on this. If you remember I was trying tesseract but it is too slow for my volume of data so I am resorting to using Google API but its a bit insulting to me as a developer that I couldnt come up with a solution.